# ¿Cóomo puedo entrar en un directorio con python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un problema y es que intento automatizar un proceso, dentro del cual debo entrar a una carpeta en mi escritorio llamada casos,para ello hago lo siguiente:

`subprocess.Popen("cd ruta",shell = True)`

**Pero esto tampoco funciona, asi que intente de las siguientes maneras:**

`subprocess.call("cd ruta",shell = True)`

`subprocess.run("cd ruta",shell = True)`

`subprocess.check_output("cd ruta",shell = True)`

`os.system("cd ruta")`

**Pero tampoco entra al directorio, que puedo hacer?**

Hice una pregunta sobre las diferencias entre los métodos `call`, `run`, `check_output` y la clase Popen, por favor también ayúdenme con esa otra duda.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al usar `os.getcwd()` te devolverá el directorio de trabajo **actual**.

Luego si haces `os.listdir()` te mostrará una lista con los nombres de los archivos que se encuentran en el directorio que le pases por parametro, por defecto retornará los archivos del directorio actual.

Dicho esto.. ahora puedes usar `os.chdir(TU_RUTA)` y eso cambiará el directorio de trabajo actual a la ruta especificada en `TU_RUTA`. Para verificar que se haya cambiado, puedes usar `os.getcwd()` o `os.listdir()` para verificar que efectivamente se haya cambiado.